# How to get User's account ID in Display Form

Tags: 2010, user-accounts, display-form

I want to get the User Account ID inside of a 'Person or Group' field in my Display Form:

[image]

is it possible?

Comment: What do you want to do with the ID?

Comment: I want to campare with current user: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser()

Comment: Can you select that element using dev tools to get the class name? I can build you some jQuery to get the user displayed and compare with the current user. In 2013 the class for user links is 'ms-peopleux-userdisplink'. Is that correct for 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little script to determine your requirement. This actually compares both user names so hopefully that will work for you. The alternative would be to grab the User name from the displayed text instead of querying the list again.

Open your DispForm.aspx in SharePoint designer and add this script in the 'PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead' section

```
<script>
    function GetQueryStringParams(sParam)
    {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
        {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
            {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }

    $( document ).ready(function() {        
        //var user = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser();
        var user = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
                      fieldName: "Title"
                    });

        var requester;
        var id= GetQueryStringParams('ID');

            $().SPServices({
                operation: 'GetListItems',
                async: false,
                debug: false,
                listName: 'PollVotes',
                CAMLQuery: '<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ID"/><Value Type="Counter">' + id + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query>',
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    var xNode = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row")[0];
                    if (xNode != null)
                    {
                        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                            requester = $(this).attr("ows_Requester");
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

        if(requester.split('#')[1] + " - " + user)
            alert("The Requester equals the Current User");
    });

</script>
```